# Difficulty selecting elements on page in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to build a clock in JavaScript, and currently, I'm stuck on using `querySelector` to select the appropriate elements I would want.

```js
function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
  var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59

  var time = h + ":" + m;
  
  console.log(document.querySelector('#time').textContent);
}

showTime();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="time">
    <h1 id="time">1:55</h1>
    <h3>PM</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

The console is telling me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null`.

Why is that?

Comment: I've put your code into a snippet and as you can see it is working. There must be something else in your project that is causing the problem.

Comment: You are reading the time that is already there, but you are not setting the time you just created into the H1.

Comment: Most likely your script is not waiting for the page to be loaded and ready before running. Put it *after* the body not before.

Answer (score 2):

We can clearly see that the following snippet is running correctly.

```js
function showTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
  var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
  var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59

  var time = h + ":" + m;
  
  console.log(document.querySelector('#time').textContent);
}

showTime();
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="time">
    <h1 id="time">1:55</h1>
    <h3>PM</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

There must be a different problem with your project. The most probable guess is that your script is executing before the `#time` has loaded.
You can fix it in a couple of ways.

**1. Put the `script` tag at the end of body.**
This way you ensure that the script will only be called when the body has completed loading.

```html
<body>
  <div class="time">
    <h1 id="time">1:55</h1>
    <h3>PM</h3>
  </div>
  ...

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**2. Look for `window.onload`**
Only run the code when the window has loaded.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  function showTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
    var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
    var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
    var time = h + ":" + m;

    console.log(document.querySelector('#time').textContent);
  }

  showTime();
}
```

**3. Use the `defer` attribute**
`defer` attribute ensures that the element to which it is attached loads at the end i.e. after the page has completed loading. This way you can even add the `script` tag in the `head`.

```html
<!--This script will load only when the page has completed loading-->
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was giving an error in your code was because you might have linked it inside `<head>`. The contents of `body` would not have been rendered till then, and it threw an error.

Besides that, you did not changed the time value, you just obtained it, and didn't use it.

I have added the code here working fine...

**NOTE :** Always link your JS or jQuery code just before the closing `body` tag.

```html
<body>
  <div class="time">
    <h1 id="time">1:55</h1>
    <h3>PM</h3>
  </div>
  <script>
    function showTime() {
      var date = new Date();
      var h = date.getHours(); // 0 - 23
      var m = date.getMinutes(); // 0 - 59
      var s = date.getSeconds(); // 0 - 59
      var h3Content = "AM";

      var time = h + ":" + m;

      document.querySelector('#time').innerText = time;

      if (h > 12 & h != 24) {
        h3Content = "PM";
      } else if (h == 12) {
        h3Content = "Noon";
      }
      
      document.querySelector('.time h3').innerText = h3Content;

      console.log(document.querySelector('#time').textContent);
    }

    showTime();
  </script>
</body>
```